# Petals on Motherboard prevent ports panel to adjoin tight

Tags: motherboard, computer-building, case

please help me to figure out, trying to install MSI B250M Gaming motherboard into a computer case, but I've 2 "petals" near the ports, can see on the photos:

[image]
[image]

To be honest I've no idea what are they for, but they disallow me to adjoin mother board tight to the ports back frame. Please help me with an advice.

Comment: your motherboard should have come with a back plate that fits over the motherboards ports area, and snaps into the back of the case. Try putting this cover on the ports, and placing the motherboard from the back side first. push everthing toward the back as you seat the plate in its slot on the case, and keep pushing gently to get the case standouts to line up with the mounting holes in the board. Then add the back screws first, to hold it in place as you put in the rest of the screws. Of course, if you really can't get it to fit, you can always cut them off with some wire clippers or whatever

Comment: @FrankThomas thank you for your comment, yes I've frame that was in the same package with motherboard, and I've installed it into the case, but  once I screw mb to the case, this petals push the frame and the frame is bending plus have the gap between the frame and ports, even though the holes fit.